# Yarn: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, nuxt.js

I'm trying to follow https://codeburst.io/create-a-static-site-in-15-minutes-or-less-using-vue-js-e4e2a9945ee6 .Some of the commands appear out of date.  I'm using git-bash on win 10. I'm working on a portable flash drive. I've installed yarn using:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Then I did:

```
    $ yarn create nuxt-app nuxt1
    yarn create v1.12.3
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    warning "@vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > graphql-tag@2.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 ||
    ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0".
    warning "@vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > graphql-type-json@0.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@>=0.8.0".
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    success Installed "create-nuxt-app@2.1.1" with binaries:
          - create-nuxt-app
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    error Command failed.
    Exit code: 1
    Command: E:\nodejs\bin\create-nuxt-app
    Arguments: nuxt1
    Directory: E:\ENVS\js
    Output:
```

I don't see a nuxt app in my E:\ENVS\js folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please try `npm install -g create-nuxt-app` and run `create-nuxt-app nuxt1` at E:\ENVS\js

Comment: If you got `create-nuxt-app` command not found I will give another suggest.

Comment: This is issue from Windows

Comment: Yes ! You have solved it. Thank you! Please enter this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue come from Windows when you install `NodeJS` not via `nvm`.

Here is just my guess about this case.

Please try to install `create-nuxt-app` as global

`npm install -g create-nuxt-app`

And create your project at `E:\ENVS\js` via

`create-nuxt-app nuxt1`

Hope this can help you and other members solve this problem. xD